# Можно ли узнать включен ли звук нажатия клавиш на клавиатуре?

Tags: android, java, клавиатура

Собственно, заголовок описывает суть, тут выскажу свои рассуждения.

Клавиатура по сути отдельное приложение, а звук нажатия клавиш - это вроде как ее настройки, и мне кажется нельзя достать настройки приложения. С другой стороны, эти настройки (в случае клавиатуры google) активируются непосредственно из настроек андроида.

Если можно узнать, то можно ли их изменить из своего приложения?

Кто-нибудь знает как это на самом деле работает?

Comment: клавиатуры бывают разные.

Мое предложение - включить микрофон и попросить набрать какой то текст. Потом проанализировать звук. Если кол-во нажатий и время известно, то можно сделать анализ.

Comment: @KoVadim не, анализ звука - это не тот путь. 
Меня интересует конкретно программно. Грубо говоря, если ли какой-нибудь getter?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setSoundEffectsEnabled(boolean) и http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setHapticFeedbackEnabled(boolean) могут чем-то помочь. А так я не думаю что в API есть доступ к этому.

Comment: @Deadkenny это я сам нагуглил и попробовал, не помогло.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Непосредственно из настроек андроида производится настройка любой клавиатуры. В настройках андроида содержится список всех приложений клавиатуры, и при выборе настройки определенной клавиатуры запускается Activity с настройкой из этого приложения клавиатуры. Как именно хранятся настройки в каждом приложении ни кто не знает (кроме самого разработчика).

Максимум, что можно узнать - громкость канала звука, на котором воспроизводится звук клавиатуры (как правило, это системный канал звука). Сделать это можно так:

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
int volume_level= am.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM);
```

Где `AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM` - строковая константа, определяющая канал звука.